# Why does SQL float casting to string not work with LIKE but SQL float casting to decimal to string does work?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an object with an number of type `float`, and I was curious why the following SQL statement does not work, but the one below it does.

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [number]
FROM [object]
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(255), number) LIKE '%201608147%'
```

Results in "0 rows found".

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [number]
FROM [object]
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(255), CONVERT(decimal(20, 2), number)) LIKE '%201608147%'
```

Results in 1 row found

**Edit:** I was asked to execute the following:

```
SELECT
    number, 
    CONVERT(varchar(255), number), 
    CONVERT(varchar(255), CONVERT(decimal(20, 2), number))  
FROM [object]
```

This yielded the following result:

```
number : 201608147  
number cast to string: 201608147  
number cast to decimal: 201608147.00
```

To show it is really a float:

[image]

Comment: @jarlh my bad, i swapped out the tags.

Comment: Skip the WHERE clause for a while, and instead do `select number, Convert(varchar(255), number), Convert(varchar(255), Convert(decimal(20,2), number))  from [object]`. See any difference?

Comment: @jarlh i posted the results of the query as an edit

Comment: Is it really a float type column? I'd expect  Convert(varchar(255), number) to return 2.01608e+008.

Comment: @jarlh i adapted my question to show a photo with the datatype

Comment: Odd. I don't get the same result. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bf9c4cef1576ae476446df9e233974a9

Comment: What's the overall goal here?

Comment: @CaiusJard to understand why the convert to Decimal is necassery to do a LIKE of the number when it exceeds a certain length, like i can find number 89113 without casting and not number 20160826 for example

Comment: But why is `LIKE` the right operator to be using for searching your floats in the first place? It's an "unnatural" fit. If, in fact, you're looking for a subset of digits within the floats, it's likely that float was the wrong choice of data type to begin with. You're working with strings of digits but you don't do maths with them, so a string data type is a better model.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i totally agree with you that string would be a better fit but unfortunatly im not allowed to change the datatype because of compatibility reasons with a legacy version. 

in this case is it a number that will be searched a lot, thats why a LIKE is required.

Comment: You're going to search this number for substrings a lot?

Comment: we are using an criteriaBuilder to allow users to specificy multiple criteria, one of which is substrings of this number

Comment: Because [that's what CONVERT does to floats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#float-and-real-styles)

Comment: Change the column type, don't pile another bodge on top of a bad design decision in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After simulation I found the following:

```
select nbr, Convert(varchar(255), nbr), Convert(varchar(255), Convert(decimal(20,2), nbr))  from tbl_XYZ

201608147   2.01608e+008    201608147.00
```

The `Convert(varchar(255), nbr)` returns the scientific notation of the number at hand as a string value; consequently the value does not match your pattern :

```
LIKE '%201608147%'
```

The reason behind this behavior is that the `Float` DataType is used to hold the binary (base-2) approximation of a number and not a precise decimal value.

Floating point numbers are often shown in scientific notation. These types are used when range is more important than absolute precision.
The numbers quickly become unwieldy in other formats. Scientific notation also helps to emphasise the limited precision.
You can see the different ways that different functions can be used to format floating-point numbers in this example.

```
DECLARE @float float = 201608147;
SELECT TheNumber = @float;

SELECT  ConvertWithoutStyle = CONVERT(varchar(255),@float),
        ConvertWithStyle0   = CONVERT(varchar(255),@float,0),
        ConvertWithStyle1   = CONVERT(varchar(255),@float,1),
        ConvertWithStyle2   = CONVERT(varchar(255),@float,2),
        ConvertWithStyle3   = CONVERT(varchar(255),@float,3);
```

For a float, style can have one of the values shown below. Other values are processed as 0.

```
Value   Output
0 (default) A maximum of 6 digits. Use in scientific notation, when appropriate.
1   Always 8 digits. Always use in scientific notation.
2   Always 16 digits. Always use in scientific notation.
3   Always 17 digits. Use for lossless conversion. With this style, every distinct float or real value is guaranteed to convert to a distinct character string.
```

You are using an implicit conversion from `float` to `varchar(255)`, which implicitly uses style `0`. Your float has more than six digits, so it is represented in scientific notation.

**You might like to use STR or FORMAT instead.**

Comment: Thank you, this indeed seems to be the case. why would STR or FORMAT be a better option then Convert ?